# How to render an image the exact way its displayed in the vrendered preview

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting, scene, world

below is the whats seen in the rendered preview [image: rendered preview]

below is whats displayed when the image is rendered [image]

to make the scene dark I changed the below settings

[image]

[image]

Unwanted lights have been toggled off when rendering.It seems like its rendering with both scene and world scene toggled on. How to make the final output look exactly like the rendered preview ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You show the *Viewport Shading* settings, these settings allow you to set what you’re currently seeing in your 3D View but they won’t be taken into account for the render. For exemple you’ve disabled the *Scene World* option for the *Rendered Preview*, so you’ll see the effect of a default HDRI in your 3D view, not the effect of your *World* settings, plus you’ve set the *Strength* to 0, which means that your preview appears dark. Conclusion, if you want to have an idea of what your render will be you need to enable the *Scene World* option (and if you think it's too bright you need to decrease your *World* background strength, open the *Shader Editor* and switch to *World* instead of *Object* to see your *World* material, or check your *World Properties* panel):

[image]